# select top 5 sellers in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have the follow table in MySQL

TABLE "SALES"

```
id, product, code, quantity, amount, who-sold-it
```

while the field "who-sold-it" is just a example to understand the question but not the real name of the field

Now I have another table the name is "USERS" and it looks like this

```
id, name, sellercode
```

I need to get the top 5 sellers using the 2 tables looking the who-sold-it in each SALE and display their name and sold amounts

Comment: You need to join the two tables. See: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Provide table structure(s), example data and excepted output.. For now i vote this question to be unclear  clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Raymond, the question is very clear, the problem is you, maybe you are a new MOD trying to use some power or a MOD wannabe, b ut if you read the question you will get the scenario

Comment: Your question only makes sense if the field "who-sold-it" relates either to the field "id" or the field "sellercode" in the "USERS" table. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

Order the results by total sales and take the top 5 with `limit`. You can also join the sales table with the seller table to get the name of the seller.

```
select users.name, users.sellercode, sum(sales.amount) as total
from sales, users
where sales.sellercode = users.sellercode
group by users.sellercode, users.name
order by total desc
limit 5
```

To display the result:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name'])</td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['total'])</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: will give ti a try, any idea how to display it ?

Comment: Yes, iterate over the result and print a table row for each item.

Comment: I edited the question and gave both tables a name because I got confused with so many "seller" words and it display nothing

Comment: htmlspecialchars should always use three params especially the encoding param.. php's default charset could be different then the default or used mysql charset making the function less safe and still might get injected with cross site scripting attack vectors.

Comment: Using the explicit `INNER JOIN ... ON ...` syntax instead of the ancient implicit one, could help making the query more readable and understandable.

Comment: getting white result, nothing is displayed

Comment: there are no error in mysql, the problem must be the query about seller and sales

Comment: edited the question, please edite your answer because it must be some word in the query that we missunderstood

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_error` to report on errors? The error message would specify if an unknown table was referenced.

Comment: yes, look at the new edited question, I changed some field names and the 2 tables have names, the error must be in some field name only, look at the edited question